# Redirect all traffic to HTTPS except for one directory should force HTTP

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I tried rewrite conditions from many posts, but none seem to work.

I want to force `HTTPS` on the entire site. Except for one directory has to be forced to `HTTP`.

Everything with `www.example.com` should be `HTTPS`.

Anything in `dir3`: `www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/test.php` should be forced `HTTP`.

Here is what I have so far.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^dir3/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured out something that works, may not be the most elegant solution however.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS, except dir3 directory
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir1/dir2/dir3/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Redirect and RedirectMatch directives to control exactly which areas are forced to http and which are forced to https.  Use the permanent keyword for a 301 redirect if you want client browsers to cache the redirect (ie if it really is permanent), or omit it for a 302 (temporary) redirect.  Note that when testing if you use permanent then the browser will cache the redirect and any changes you make after that won't be seen... clearing the redirect cache in browsers can be an exercise of frustration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Redirect everything except /dir1/dir2/dir3 to use https
    RedirectMatch permanent "^(/(?!dir1/dir2/dir3/?).*)" https://www.example.com$1

    # config for the http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/ stuff goes here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Redirect /dir1/dir2/dir3 to use http
    Redirect permanent /dir1/dir2/dir3 http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3

    # config for the https://www.example.com/ stuff goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

To keep things nice and tidy you may also want redirects for example.com on both port 80 and port 443 to make sure your site is always accessed at www.example.com.  You could use ServerAlias in the VirtualHosts above instead, but specifying redirects forces the name in the client browser to always show www.example.com instead of showing whichever name the request came from.  The preference among most web sites is to force (redirect) everybody to www.example.com.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent /dir1/dir2/dir3 http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent /dir1/dir2/dir3 http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```